# Why does callback function work when there are fewer arguments?

Tags: javascript, express, web, callback, backend

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSw0x.png)

Can someone please explain why this code works when in the function verifyUser, the function verifyToken is passed a callback function as the fourth argument. But if we look at the verifyToken function, it only has 3 parameters/arguments. How does this work????

```js
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { createError } from "../utils/error.js";

export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies.access_token;
    if (!token) {
        return next(createError(401, "You are not authenticated!"));
    }
    //Verifying if token is correct
    //Error (err) or token data (user) are returned by verify function
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT, (err, user) => {
        if (err) return next(createError(403, "Token is not valid!"));
        req.user = user;
        next();
    });
};

export const verifyUser = (req, res, next) => {
    verifyToken(req, res, next, () => {
        if (req.user.id === req.params.id || req.user.isAdmin) {
            next();
        } else {
            return next(createError(403, "You are not authorized!"));
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  `verifyUser()` will call `verifyToken()` just fine (with one extra argument), but NOTHING in `verifyToken()` will call that callback passed as the fourth argument.  If you think that is really happening, then please offer a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can run and debug ourselves because apparently something else other than just the code we see here is going on.

Comment: My theory here is that the callback you pass to `verifyToken()` is NEVER called.  Your code appears to work because `verifyToken()` calls `next()` which continues routing and makes things appear to work.  Your test for `if (req.user.id === req.params.id || req.user.isAdmin)` is probably never run.  You can verify that by putting a `console.log("in my callback passed to verifyToken()");` inside of that callback.

Comment: Where'd you go?  We're trying to help and to clarify the question and you're not here to respond.  We can't help effectively if you're not going to be here to clarify things.

Comment: Question has been answered below

Comment: So, are you agreeing that your fourth argument callback is never executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went digging in Express's source code and found this documentation

> Once the `next()` function is invoked, just like middleware
> it will continue on to execute the route, or **subsequent parameter functions.**

[Source](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js)

So it looks like `next()` first tries to call a callback argument if it it's passed, then tries to call the next middleware.

I think the reason they did this, is to hardcode or chain a call to `verifyToken` before `verifyUser` without changing their implementation of `next()` which would jump to the next middleware when called in `verifyToken` instead of continuing `verifyUser`.

I wrote an example script that uses the same idea here:

```js
function printResult(object, next) {
  console.log("The final results is: " + object.result);
  next();
}

function printLog(object, next){
  console.log('Running printLog')
  console.log('The current result is: ' + object.result)
  next();
}

function add5(object, next) {
  // Chain printLog before add5 so that it always runs before it
  printLog(object, next, () => {
    console.log('Now running add5')
    object.result = object.result + 5;
    next();
  })
}


function addOne(object, next) {
  console.log('Running addOne')
  object.result = object.result + 1;
  next();
}

function callStack(stack, object) {

  function next(index, object) {
    return function runNext() {
       let caller = runNext.caller
       if(caller.name !== '' && caller.arguments[2]) {
          caller.arguments[2]()
       } else if (stack[index + 1]){
          stack[index + 1](object, next(index + 1, object));
       }
     }  
   }
   
  stack[0](object, next(0, object)); 
}

const stack = [addOne, add5, printResult]
const object = {result: 0}

callStack(stack, object)
```

Note that the anonymous function check `caller.name !== ''` is there because checking the arguments property of an anonymous function throws an error.

### More thorough explanation of why this is important.

#### So if you're app is like this there's no problem:

- Middleware 1

  - `next()` goes to next middleware
- verifyToken (Middleware 2)

  - `next()` goes to next middleware
- Middleware 3

#### But if it was like this and `next()` *didn't* call the parameter function:

- Middleware 1

  - `next()` goes to next middleware
- `verifyUser` (Middleware 2)

  - calls `verifyToken`

    - `next()` in `verifyToken` goes to next middleware <- This is an issue
  - Continue `verifyUser` <- Because this never happens
  - `next()` goes to next middleware
- Middleware 3

#### So they let `next()` call a parameter function:

- Middleware 1

  - `next()` goes to next middleware
- `verifyUser` (Middleware 2)

  - calls `verifyToken` with `verifyUser`'s implementation as a callback `veryifyCB` (jus an alias for th example)

    - `next()` in `verifyToken` checks for a callback, finds `verifyCB` and calls it
  - `next()` in `verifyCB` goes to next middleware
- Middleware 3

---

Comment: Yup! This is exactly what I was looking for!